# CSS not loading on Local Host ("Failed to Load Resource")

Tags: css, node.js, express

I've been looking at some of the answers on this forum but nothing seems to work.

My main HTML file refers to the style sheet as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
```

I have an index.js file with the following code:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();              
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {        
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname});                                                      
});

app.listen(port, () => {            
    console.log(`Now listening on port ${port}`); 
});
```

Finally, this is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure screenshot]

I'd really appreciate some guidance on this

Comment: You never serve the file

Comment: Sorry if this seems super simple -- I'm new at this. I've tried to follow different of the recommended solutions in there, but still not able to make it work.

This is the last change i made on the code before "app.get":

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));`

Anything else I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: nevermind! it worked. I had to restart the local host through the terminal

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

I needed to add the following code to my index.js file before the "app.get" portion:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

***NOTE:** re-starting the LocalHost instance is also necessary after modifying index.js file*

Answer (score -1):

You can serve static files using `express.static`, like this:

```js
app.use('/styles', express.static('styles'));
app.get('/', ...
```

See this documentation, https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html .

Comment: I was not able to make it work either with the sample code you've provided